Amenable non-Hausdorff groupoids
Is there any clear definition of amenable non Hausdorff groupoids? It should be possibly non-separable nuclear C*-algebras? Please let me know if there is any existing literature talking about this.

Why do you think such groupoids would have anything to do with nonseparability of associated Cstar algebras?

because etale hausdorff groupoids has countable bisections covering any open set

I don't follow the reasoning at all. Take any discrete uncountable group, then its reduced Cstar algebra is non-separable.

I took my words back, discard the non-separability, What is the exact definition of non-hausdorff amenble groupoids?

You may find the definition of amenable groupoid (for non Hausdorff étale groupoids as well) in my paper with Buss https://arxiv.org/pdf/2302.14466 (see definition 4.23). Nevertheless, as Yemon Choi pointed out, non Hausdorffness has nothing to do with separability of the algebra.

Just to add to my comment, the definition of amenability is the same in the Hausdorff/non-Hausdorff settings (as long as $G$ is assumed to be étale). In particular, what we want are functions $(\xi_i)_i \subset C_c(G)$ such that $||\xi_i^* * \xi_i|| \leq 1$ and $\xi_i^* * \xi_i$ converges to $1$ uniformly over compact sets of $G$. In the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2302.14466 it is proven (albeit in a very roundabout way) that if $G$ is amenable then $C_{red}^*(G) \cong C_{max}^*(G)$ is a nuclear C*-algebra.
Note that by $C_c(G)$ here we mean the set of functions $a \colon G \to \mathbb{C}$ that are finite linear combinations of functions that are continuous and compactly supported on some open bisection of $G$. Thus, elements in $C_c(G)$ are not continuous as functions on $G$, but if $G$ is Hausdorff then they actually are. I hope this helps.

Can you provide some examples reference?

What do you mean? Whether I can provide some examples of amenable groupoids? Examples 4.8 and 4.9 in the paper I referenced are somewhat enlightening.

I mean examples of non-Hausdorff amenable groupoids. Does groupoids of germs give an example of such?

Again, look at example 4.9 in the paper. Any étale groupoid is a groupoid of germs of an inverse semigroup action (some people may disagree what 'germs' means here, but what I said is true with the notion of germs in that paper). And, thus, some groupoids of germs are amenable, some are not. It depends on the groupoid itself.
